# Show last 4 divs from another page of my website

Tags: javascript, html, show

I have this page myurl.de/news
on this page i just write some weekly short news inside seperate divs like this

```
<div class="guidediv">
<p>Date: 25.08.2023</p>
<p>Some News text</P>
</div>

<div class="guidediv">
<p>Date: 25.08.2023</p>
<p>Some News text</P>
</div>

<div class="guidediv">
<p>Date: 18.08.2023</p>
<p>Some News text</P>
</div>

<div class="guidediv">
<p>Date: 18.08.2023</p>
<p>Some News text</P>
</div>
```

and so on...

Now i want to show the last 4 divs on another page myurl.de/page2

The News page will be get new News every week and on my Page 2 i want to show just a preview respectively just the newest 4 news.

is this possible by javascript?

hope for your help

Comment: There is little to no context in this question. If you just have 2 HTML pages and you want to display some HTML elements from page 1 at page 2, then at page 2 you can download the whole page 1 and get desired elements. Though its the worst scenario ever. It would be much more simple to have some kind of data source which is used to create these elements, and use this source in page 1 and page 2